# Multithreaded Console Application array deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

I have been struggling with a multi-threaded issue lately. I have a C# console application that trains neural networks. I spawn a thread via a task for each network I am going to train. I created a status update event for my trainer class that the parent class subscribe to. In that event handler, I update a status array with that model's new status. That array access is where I am seeing a 'deadlock' type of behavior. I understand that is not the canonical definition of a deadlock, but I can't think of a better term to describe the situation. Below is my code. I have condensed it as much as I am able to.

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Parent Code

```
public class TrainingEngine
{
    public enum UpdateStatus
    {
        Untrimmed = 0,
        Trimmed,
        Completed
    }

    private class TrainingStatus
    {
        public int Epoch { get; set; }
        public UpdateStatus UpdateStatus { get; set; }
    }

    private static readonly object printLock = new object();

    private ConcurrentDictionary<int, TrainingStatus> trainingStatus;

    ...other stuff...

    private void UpdateEpochCompleted(TrainingStatus newStatus)
    {
        trainingStatus[newStatus.ThreadId] = newStatus;
        PrintUpdate($"Model {newStatus.ThreadId + 1} completed epoch {newStatus.Epoch}.");
    }

    private void PrintUpdate(string trigger)
    {
        lock (printLock)
        {
            logger.Info(""); /***** DEADLOCKS HERE *****/

            logger.Info($"  {trigger}");
            foreach (TrainingStatus status in trainingStatus.Values)
            {
                if (status.Status == TrainingStatus.UpdateStatus.Completed)
                {
                    logger.Info(
                        $"    {status.Status.ToString()} model {status.ThreadId + 1}",
                        100);
                }
                else
                {
                    logger.Info(
                        $"    {status.Status.ToString()} model {status.ThreadId + 1} working on epoch {status.Epoch} / {epochCount}",
                        100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Worker Definition

```
public class NetworkTrainer
{
    IProgress<TrainingStatus> UpdateCompleted { get; set; }


        private double TrainNetwork(ActivationNetwork network,
            int epochCount,
            int geneCount,
            double[][] inputData,
            double[][] outputData,
            int threadId,
            bool trimmedModel)
        {

            for (int idxEpoch = 0; idxEpoch < epochCount; ++idxEpoch)
            {
                error += teacher.RunEpoch(inputData,
                    outputData);

                UpdateCompleted?.Report(new TrainingStatus
                {
                    Epoch = idxEpoch,
                    Status =  (trimmedModel) ? TrainingStatus.UpdateStatus.Trimmed : TrainingStatus.UpdateStatus.Untrimmed,
                    ThreadId = threadId,
                });
            }

            return error;
        }
}
```

Deadlock screenshot
[image]

Comment: exactly what behavior are you seeing

Comment: I have an example right now in my debugger. I have 3 worker threads that are all stuck on the trainingStatus[..] update line I commented on. All three threads are updating different elements in the array. It seems like the lock object isn't honored and 3 updates occur concurrently instead of waiting for the previous update to finish.

Comment: that line is the top stack frame?

Comment: since you give no indication of what TrainingStatus is nor what the UpdateStatus property looks like its hard to say why it would be stuck there

Comment: Yeah the `                trainingStatus[threadId].UpdateStatus = trimmedModel // This is always where the deadlock occurs.
                    ? UpdateStatus.Trimmed
                    : UpdateStatus.Untrimmed;` line

Comment: Updated with the TrainingStatus and UpdateStatus definitions.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `lock`? Seems each thread has access to only one `trainingStatus[threadId]`, so is this just to synchronize access to `PrintUpdate`?

Comment: I was trying to guard against simultaneous array writes. You're correct in that each thread as its own object, so each element should only be written by its thread. After I first encountered this lockup, I figured I needed to guard against any array writes, which is why I added the lock. I will add the PrintUpdate code momentarily. Inside that function, I call a logger, which is just a wrapper I wrote around NLog that protects against simultaneous writes using a Mutex

Comment: Lock is redundand here as well as volatile keyword, but what is missing here is TrainingStatus definition. And btw fighting deadlocks by adding locks sounds at least weird so I'm not sure it's a deadlock problem at all.

Comment: I posted the definition for TrainingStatus in the first block. Its just a data class containing an integer and a enum, UpdateStatus. I would also like to appologize, the deadlock is occuring on the line: trainingStatus[threadId].Epoch = epochCompleted; I edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I thought I would need the volatile keyword to denote multithread access to a variable.

Comment: @jecjackal what are you trying to do? It's almost certain there are simpler ways to do it. Why use `UpdateCompleted?.Invoke` for example? Describe the problem you want to solve in the question itself, not how you thought it can be solved.

Comment: @jecjackal for example, if you train each network in a separate thread, just return the results from the task instead of using `Invoke` like this. If you want to report progress on the other hand, use `IProgress<T>` and the `Progress<T>` class as described in [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the threads window please. I really see no way 3 threads could enter this lock at the same time. Also, I believe you do not understand what a deadlock is. Maybe you should find out because it's misleading to claim there is a deadlock here. If anything there is too little blocking, not too much.

Comment: I think the IProgress solution is exactly what I am looking for @PanagiotisKanavos. I will try that this evening. Unfortunately, the deadlock only occurs after 4 days of training, so I will likely not have an update until then.

Comment: @usr I will share a screenshot of the thread window if my attempt at using IProgress deadlocks again. I do believe it is a deadlock, because at the top of each call stack of each thread is a call to Monitor.enter(). What I found strange is that Monitor.Enter() was being called after the thread was already inside the lock. I could be wrong, and I am fairly new to multi-threaded applications, and I apologize if I used the wrong term. I went through a few quick tutorials and thought I understood progress reporting, and evidently I need to do more research.

Comment: @jecjackal Progress<T> won't deadlock - it doesn't need any locks in the first place. The event or delegate you provide is called on the same thread that created it. You don't need to put a lock around `trainingStatus` if you try to update it from inside the progress delegate. Of course, if the parent thread itself is blocked, you'll get a deadlock again. Does your `Main()` method have a `.Result` or `.Wait()` perhaps?

Comment: @jecjackal another possibility is to use a `ConcurrentDictionary<int,TrainingStatus>` instead of an array where the key is the thread ID. `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe for modification of the dictionary itself. You could *replace* the `TrainingStatus` value with a new one without requiring a lock

Comment: `Monitor.Enter() was being called after the thread was already inside the lock` that sounds like reentrancy (e.g. you calling an event from inside the lock which then causes the lock to be taken again. What does PrintUpdate do? Please post the stack of the deadlocked threads. Need to analyze all evidence and carefully interpret that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Wow, sorry about my last reply; it didn't make any sense. I tried to write it quickly while at work. I understand why I don't need a lock now. Thanks. I also just updated my question with my revised code using the ConcurrentDictionary and IProgress updates.

Comment: @usr you are probably right about this being a reentrancy problem. If the IProgress and ConcurrentDictionary changes doesn't work, and I have another issue, I'll post the stacktrace.

Comment: I ran some tests this morning by disabling the actual work and replacing it with Thread.Sleep(10). After 8 runs, I didn't encounter any deadlocks. I am trying a real run now, and if it works I'll mark this question as answered. It will probably take about 5-6 days to finish. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: The application deadlocked again. This time it froze at the first logger.Info() line after acquiring the lock. I will update a picture of my threads' call stacks shortly.

Comment: I added the PrintUpdate() method definition since that is where the problem has moved to. If you look at my Threads, I have dozens now stuck at that location. Logger is simply NLogger's logger that is setup to write both to a file and to the terminal. I wanted to lock these status prints to keep them together; I didn't want overlapping status writing from multiple threads. Is there a problem with my lock definition? Also, I have kept the debugger paused on the deadlock, so I can provide additional information. I'm not sure what else would be helpful.

Comment: I am trying SemaphoreSlim with a limit of 1, instead of lock. I will let everyone know how that goes.

Comment: The lock looks fine. Is there a thread that's currently inside of the lock? What is it's call stack. Include external code (right click the callstack window). There must be one thread inside the lock and all others waiting to enter the lock.; For testing maybe you can provoke the hang quicker by increasing the logging frequency (or doing nothing but logging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. First, I would like to thank everyone who helped me, especially Panagiotis Kanavos and usr. Initially, I had a poorly written lock statement, which was vulnerable to reentrency. Looking at my code, I couldn't see how such a such a condition could occur. After all, each epoch of training would take approximately 30 minutes. After some investigation, I learned that when I click on a terminal window and leave a white square on the window (the marker), I have locked access the terminal. This meant my threads were no longer able to write to the terminal; I was causing the deadlock. Occasionally, I was doing other things on the laptop while it trained my models, and I would click on the terminal to see the current status.

tl;dr. If you click the terminal, press enter to release it back to the system.

Comment: Just change the option.  Press Alt+Space > Properties > Options tab > untick "QuickEdit Mode".

Comment: This is a really interesting failure mode! :)